# I see the POV of the other player in the grass in my local multiplayer coop game

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, multiplayer, terrain, grass

I apologize for the wording of my request, but I'm not used to posting questions, and my head is spinning right now.
I have a local multiplayer game with split-screen, so I have two cameras in my scene. My multiplayer is working fine; I've differentiated the two players with their respective inputs.

Now, I'm trying to manage the scenery, and I wanted to add grass to my terrain. As you can see in the attached screenshot, each player sees the other player's perspective in the grass.

Has anyone encountered this issue before, and how can it be resolved?

[image: See the little pixels in the grass]

Comment: it looks like the local player (I assume right) is a different scale to the one on the left assuming they are the same object

Comment: There are not the same object. But either way it doesn’t answer my grass problem x)

Comment: perhaps you can try be clearer what you mean, I dont know what you expect or dont expect to see

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity in my request.
In summary, when I place grass on my terrain, there are invisible pixels around the grass that display the viewpoint of the camera of the other player. This results in a kind of reflection in the grass from the perspective of the other player.
I've just updated the screenshot in the post for better visibility. On the right player looking at the grass, you can clearly discern the viewpoint of the other player (on the left) within the grass.
It's not likable, I don"t want to see the other viewpoint in the grass.

Comment: can you rotate the red player? -> Is it really related to the viewport or maybe just the camera distance from the grass (like maybe some Distance LOD effect)?